# DIY Antenna Tuning

Tags: antenna

I know that getting a perfect tuning network for an antenna and transceiver requires some rather expensive equipment plus human knowledge to operate the equipment. I have never done any antenna tuning, but I would like to know if there is any way a DIYer can perform at least a semi-decently good match.

Is there any way I can use an oscope to do this? Is there any difference between tuning a PCB antenna versus a wire antenna?

Comment: what frequency range?

Comment: I am looking at 2.4GHz, but would consider lower (434 or 900) if it was the only way to tune myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the "Dropout's guide to antenna design"

http://colinkarpfinger.com/blog/2010/the-dropouts-guide-to-antenna-design/

Comment: I like that they call it an NA.

Comment: I worked with a guy whom could look at the smith chart every time and put the components on that would tune to 50 ohm. He had been doing it for years he could tell how the parts would react.

Comment: Very helpful. Still requires expensive equipment though.

Answer (score 0):

Could make use of the RSSI (Received Signal Strength Indicator) on many RF transcievers to give you a rough indication.

Comment: Rough is the operative word.